# Jolt transformation for spatial data (from geojson to arcGIS json)

Tags: transformation, jolt

I'm new to Jolt transformation and am trying to write a spec for spatial data. I'm unable to get the 
expected output especially with the data for the coordinates.  Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Below is the input I get:

```
{
"type": "Feature Collection",
"c rs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "4326"
    }
  },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 1,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -122.682207049,
          45.526159497
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "F ID": 1,
        "Place Name": "Boyd Coffee",
        "Place Address": "404 NW 11th Ave Portland Oregon",
        "Score": 100,
        "latitude": 45.526159497,
        "longitude": -122.682207049
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 2,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -122.677518466,
          45.525246078
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "F ID": 2,
        "Place Name": "John's Coffee Shop",
        "Place Address": "301 NW Broadway St Portland Oregon",
        "Score": 100,
        "lat": 45.525246078,
        "l on": -122.677518466
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 3,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -122.68287749,
          45.526496967
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "F ID": 3,
        "Place Name": "Starbucks",
        "Place Address": "1134 NW  St Portland Oregon",
        "Score": 100,
        "latitude": 45.526496967,
        "longitude": -122.68287749
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The expected output is -

```
"features": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "F ID": 1,
                "Place Name": "Boyd Coffee",
                "Place Address": "404 NW 11th Ave Portland Oregon",
                "Score": 100,
                "latitude": 45.526159497,
                "longitude": -122.682207049
            },
            "geometry": {
                "x": -122.68220704900002,
                "y": 45.526159496999998
            }
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "FID": 2,
                "Place Name": "John's Coffee Shop",
                "Place Address": "301 NW Broadway St Portland Oregon",
                "Score": 100,
                "latitude": 45.525246078,
                "longitude": -122.677518466
            },
            "geometry": {
                "x": -122.677518466,
                "y": 45.52524607799999
            }
        }

    ]
```

I've come up with spec as below, and not getting the expected out. Can anyone help please?
The spec is:

```
 [
      {
        "operation": "shift",
        "spec": {
          "features": {
            "*": {
              "properties": "features[&1].attributes",
              "geometry": {
                "coordinates": {
                  "0": "features[&].geometry.x",
                  "1": "features[&].geometry.y"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Can anyone help me please?  or any help on Jolt documentation or guide?

Answer (score 0):

Change the below in your spec

`"0": "features[&].geometry.x",` **->** `"0": "features[&3].geometry.x",`

`"1": "features[&].geometry.y",` **->** `"1": "features[&3].geometry.y",`

```
 [
   {
     "operation": "shift",
     "spec": {
       "features": {
         "*": {
           "properties": "features[&1].attributes",
           "geometry": {
             "coordinates": {
               "0": "features[&3].geometry.x",
               "1": "features[&3].geometry.y"
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
      }
    ]
```